# 403 Forbidden CGI script

Tags: windows-7, apache2, cgi

i'm trying to execute .cgi file on my server but return the following error

```
403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /run/test.cgi on this server.
Apache/2.0.64 (Win32) Server at localhost Port 80
```

server conf:

- windows 7
- apache 2
- activeperl

i tried various solutions but none working

Set the permissions on /run/test.cgi to readable and executable > not working

tried to change Options indexes > not working

```
<Directory "E:/Apache/Apache2/htdocs">
#    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

my directory is under "E:/Apache/Apache2/htdocs/run/test.cgi"

the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
print "testing...\n";
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser';
#print qq`Perl_version: $]\n`;
#print qq`CGI::VERSION: $CGI::VERSION\n`;
foreach my $var (sort keys %ENV)
{
#   print "$var: $ENV{$var}\n";
}
#print "\nExecuting 'which convert':\n";
#print "\n";
#print "\nExecuting 'find / -name convert':\n";
#print `find / -name convert`;
```

can anyone help?
thanks

Comment: solved
http://usefulscripts.wordpress.com/2007/10/17/installing-perl-cgi-in-apache-windows-platform/